# Activity not stopping when i press back button

Tags: android, android-activity

In my project, when i click on the button in the first Activity it goes to a second activity. Second Activity plays a video. Video works fine, but when i the press back button on phone it goes back to the first Activity but video sound is still on, meaning video is still playing. How can i stop it when i press back button or click back ?

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
   if (position == 0) {
          Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gnrl.class);
          startActivity(int0);
      }

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId") public class gnrl extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.matematik);
    String[] myArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Matematik1);
ArrayAdapter<String> aad= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArray);
setListAdapter(aad);

ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listmat);


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
 if (position == 0) {
        Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Test.class);
        startActivity(int0);
    }
}
  });
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> aad) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: show code of second activity.

Comment: oke i wrote ? test is vimeo player with HTML5

Comment: When you exit from activity playing video, stop the playback.

Comment: yes how can i stop that video on background ? its working on background ?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onPause method of the second activity and stop the video playback there.

Comment: plss look my profile i wrote my e-mail adress i can send u my project maybe u can look that ? if u help me i can pay a few money im a student :D ?

http://stackoverflow.com/users/3576980/user3576980

Comment: send me a empty message i will send my message.i can't write all my think here :S

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` when you leave the activity playing the video.

`protected void onPause() {
        finish();
  }`

Or if you want to leave the activity after pressing a button, do something like

```
Button goBackButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
....
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent goBackToMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goBackToMainActivity);
    finish();
}
});
```

But remember,this also stops the video from playing if for instance your phone goes into sleep mode, or anything else that interferes with the activity (dialogs etc.).

I advice you take a couple of minutes to read up on the basics of `Activity` in Android.[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) is a good place to start.

Alternatively, in the manifest you can set the `"noHistory"` attribute in your activity element to `true`.
Read more on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)